# MySQL use the query result twice

Tags: mysql, sql

I have `(HARD BIG REQUEST)` and want to create new table with some logic.

I imagine it like:

```
SELECT A.col1, B.col1, A.col2, B.col2 ... A.col5, B.col5
FROM (HARD BIG REQUEST) as A, A as B
WHERE A.col3 = B.col3 and A.col2!=B.col2 and A.col1 != B.col1
```

If i try to make it with table it will be easy:

```
SELECT A.col1, B.col1, A.col2, B.col2 ... A.col5, B.col5
FROM sometable as A, sometable as B
WHERE A.col3 = B.col3 and A.col2!=B.col2 and A.col1 != B.col1
```

But how i can make it without twice request?

Twice request which I try to avoid:

```
SELECT A.col1, B.col1, A.col2, B.col2 ... A.col5, B.col5
FROM (HARD BIG REQUEST) as A, (HARD BIG REQUEST) as B
WHERE A.col3 = B.col3 and A.col2!=B.col2 and A.col1 != B.col1
```

Comment: I would never imagine a query that has commas in the `from` clause.  Learn to use proper, explicit, standard `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, you can definitely write `select * from MyTable_1 A, MyTable_2 B, ...`. Depending on the conditions you put in place, the result may look much like a `JOIN`. So, from the syntactic point of view, it is LEGAL (not wise, but legal).

Comment: @GordonLinoff nevermind, how i can make join itself without twice request?

Comment: @FDavidov One *can* teach ones grandmother to suck eggs, but one *wouldn't* advise it.

Comment: @Strawberry, nice saying!!!! I assumed that Gordon's remark was about LANGUAGE SUPPORT and not BEST PRACTICES. Hence my comment. As per BEST PRACTICES, I think that no possibility should totally be ruled out. See the never-ending arguments about GOTOs. You will find many experienced (old) programmers that will say _if used with caution, it may sometimes be a good ides_ while others (young) wound simply say _Over my death body!!_.

Comment: Views have very limited capacity to use indexes, so I'd just hard code the query twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you are using MySQL version 8+, you have basically two choices:

- A view
- A temporary table

Earlier versions of MySQL do not support common table expressions (CTEs).  These are like subqueries introduced with the `WITH` clause.  Unlike subqueries, they can be referenced multiple times.  They would be the typical way to express the query.

Comment: ok. i just only start learn mysql, so i will try to search something about view. temporary table looks bad decision for me. thank you.